# Navigating through links of categories and subcategories using Selenium, how to collect them?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

[image: categories]

I want to parse category links with subcategories into a non-binary tree or into a dictionary with dictionaries so that there is a connection.
**How it should be: collecting a list of main categories, I go through the main categories in a loop and pass it to the function. The function receives a list as input, clicks on a link, receives a list of subcategories, clicks on each subcategory, and so on until it receives a link. Moreover, in any position after a click, the subcategory will not have descendants, this needs to be taken into account, you need to either go back and continue parsing its neighbors, or some other method.**

```
def loop_dict_traversal(paginator_next, root, end):
    index = 0
    list_node = []
    list_node.append("root||"+paginator_next[0].get_attribute("textContent"))
    root = Node("root||"+paginator_next[0].get_attribute("textContent"))
    while True:
        try:
            paginator_next = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                    (By.XPATH, '//v-accordion[contains(@class, "categoryPanel")]//v-pane-content//ul//li//a')))

            if driver.current_url == end and index >= len(paginator_next)-1:
                print("List Category END!")
                break
            print(paginator_next[index].get_attribute("textContent"))
            list_node.append(f'child{len(paginator_next)}||{paginator_next[index].get_attribute("textContent")}')
            paginator_next[index].click()
            time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 10))
            scroll_distance = random.randint(10, 50)
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollBy(0, {scroll_distance});")
            print("---->>>", index)
        except:
            print("----end", index)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 8))
            break
    print(list_node)
```

```
I tried algorithms with a queue, with subcategory recursion, everything that is available on the network did not work. The only code that partially works is below. But it collects one link to the end, if I can change the indexes on the stack, then I think I can get a large list of links. But I don’t know how to connect later :)
```

Please, who understands Python, trees, maybe dictionaries, who has worked with Selenium, give an example or help solve this problem